# Android proximity sensor

Tags: android, sensors, proximity

A few years (and several API's) ago I made an app that turned off the screen when the lid/cover was closed (but the app didn't go to sleep). I'm trying to do it again but I can't remember if I used the proximity sensor or Wake lock. I've been trying with the below code. If I put my finger on the sensor it fires a 'onSensorChanged' event but not if I just close the lid/cover over the sensor. Any bright ideas anyone?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private  SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private  Sensor mProximity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    }
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensor change detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
                private  SensorManager mSensorManager;
                private  Sensor mProximity;
        PowerManager powerManager;
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
                    mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
               wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "aodplus:pocket_mode");
                }
                public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                }
                public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
     boolean isNear = event.values[0] < mProximity.getMaximumRange();
                if(isNear){
                 // near
                   turnOffScreen();
                }
    else {
                 // far
                   turnOnScreen();
                }
            }
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Sensor change detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                protected void onResume() {
                    super.onResume();
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                }
                protected void onPause() {
                    super.onPause();
                    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                }
        public void turnOnScreen(){
        
                if(wakeLock.isHeld()) wakeLock.release();
            }
        
            @TargetApi(21) //Suppress lint error for PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK
            public void turnOffScreen(){
              wakeLock.acquire( /*10 minutes*/);
        
            }
            }
```

Comment: Hi Khalid Lakhani, thanks for the effort. I tried your code after adding WakeLock permission. It does turn off the screen if I put my finger right on the sensor. It usually don't react when I take the finger away (doesn't turn on the screen). It turns on the screen when I push the on/off button quickly. Nothing happens when I close the lid (over the sensor), which is when I want the PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK to be aquired. This is about how my own efforts worked before. I'm starting to think that the proximity sensor on my Samsung sucks and it is not related to the coding.

Comment: It could be your device not working precisely coz I see lots of devices with non Qualcomm devices dont work sometimes with proximity sensor. I never tried my code with cover but it works fine in pocket

Comment: One more thing check the log when you loft off the finger whether it returns value 5 or not